# Microsoft Access - Using multiple combo boxes to set up a report

Tags: ms-access

Ok, I lack expertise in VBA.  I want to use 5 combo boxes and 2 text boxes as the parameters to look up and generate a report based off of those selections. It pulls the information of all applicable database entries and puts them into the report that is generated when i click the command button. I have the 2 text boxes setup as from and to date boxes that I pulled off of another site. Basically i want to be able to use this existing code and add the information for all the other combo boxes.  Please let me know if this is even possible. I included attachments to try to clarify this a little bit.

Page setup and brief description:

[image]

```vb
Private Sub Submit_Click()

On Error GoTo Err_Handler      'Remove the single quote from start of this line once you have it working.
'Purpose:       Filter a report to a date range.
'Documentation: http://allenbrowne.com/casu-08.html
'Note:          Filter uses "less than the next day" in case the field has a time component.
Dim strReport As String
Dim strDateField As String
Dim strWhere As String
Dim lngView As Long
Const strcJetDate = "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#"  'Do NOT change it to match your local settings.

'DO set the values in the next 3 lines.
strReport = "Search"            'Put your report name in these quotes.
strDateField = "[Date]"         'Put your field name in the square brackets in these quotes.
lngView = acViewReport          'Use acViewNormal to print instead of preview.

'Build the filter string.
If IsDate(Me.startdate) Then
    strWhere = "(" & strDateField & " >= " & Format(Me.startdate, strcJetDate) & ")"
End If
If IsDate(Me.enddate) Then
    If strWhere <> vbNullString Then
        strWhere = strWhere & " AND "
    End If
    strWhere = strWhere & "(" & strDateField & " < " & Format(Me.enddate + 1, strcJetDate) & ")"
End If

'Close the report if already open: otherwise it won't filter properly.
If CurrentProject.AllReports(strReport).IsLoaded Then
    DoCmd.Close acReport, strReport
End If
'Open the report.
Debug.Print strWhere        'Remove the single quote from the start of this line for debugging purposes.
DoCmd.OpenReport strReport, lngView, , strWhere

Exit_Handler:
Exit Sub

Err_Handler:
If Err.Number <> 2501 Then
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbExclamation, "Cannot open report"
End If
Resume Exit_Handler

End Sub
```

Comment: Date filter works? Field names in reports query match ComboBox names? All criterias have to be selected?

Comment: Date filter works, field names match and all criteria’s do not need to be selected.